# 'CAIRO_GOBJECT_TYPE_SURFACE' undeclared

Tags: cairo

Compiling **gtk+-3.7.10** in Mac OSX 10.7.5 and always getting error:

```
In file included from gdkwindow.c:28:
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-gobject.h:183:3: error: #error Cairo was not compiled with support for GObject
gdkwindow.c: In function 'gdk_window_class_init':
gdkwindow.c:511: error: 'CAIRO_GOBJECT_TYPE_SURFACE' undeclared (first use in this function)
gdkwindow.c:511: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
gdkwindow.c:511: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[4]: *** [gdkwindow.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I compiled cairo 1.10 with:

**./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gobject=yes**

But always getting the same error.
glib-2.35.8 is compiled as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the (important) first error:

```
/usr/local/include/cairo/cairo-gobject.h:183:3: error: #error Cairo was not compiled with support for GObject
```

You say you've compiled Cairo with GObject enabled, but whatever Cairo GTK+ is compiling against doesn't have it enabled. Check to make sure you installed your Cairo and that some other version of Cairo is not interfering.